# Add recipient tab to a sent envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I have a requirement to add a new tab to a recipient on an existing envelope. The only catch is the envelope is already sent (but not signed) by the time the logic needs to add it. 
The documentation mentions "This adds one or more tabs for a recipient to a **draft envelope**":

DocuSign REST Guide - Add Tabs for Recipient:

```
http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST API References/Add Tabs for a Recipient.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%20API%20References%7C_____61
```

Is there a way to fulfill my requirement?

Comment: FYI I've updated my answer- this functionality will be available in the next version (v3) of the REST api...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can not add recipient tabs to In-Process (or sent) envelopes.  As you've read in the documentation you can only add recipient tabs to draft envelopes, or add them during the envelope creation step of course.

Once an envelope has been sent, you can only edit: email, userName, signerName, routingOrder, faxNumber, and deliveryMethod.  That's directly from this page of the DocuSign REST Api Guide:

```
http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST API References/Modify or Correct and Resend Recipient Information.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%20API%20References%7C_____57
```

---

**EDIT**

However, I have found out that the ability to add recipient tabs to a sent envelope IS in the works, and should be available with v3 of the api.  Not sure when that comes out yet though...